# API test for Moodle (v2.6) with Postman

Tags: api, get, postman, moodle

Objective is to use the Moodle web services to fetch information via Postman. In this case

- Webservice function : core_enrol_get_enrolled_users
- Already created a user that had the rights to access the content
- wsToken used as a parameter

When sending the GET command in Postman, getting the below error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<EXCEPTION class="webservice_access_exception">
    <ERRORCODE>accessexception</ERRORCODE>
    <MESSAGE>Access control exception</MESSAGE>
</EXCEPTION>
```

What are the possible missing configuration for the above error ?

Comment: Did you create a web service and added that function to it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

http://www.yoursite.com/admin/settings.php?section=webservicesoverview

...where "www.yoursite.com" is the domain of your site.

and follow the steps. They are very helpful, usually.

Have you tried POSTing the request with the wstoken in the URL i.e. part of GET?

Comment: I am getting the same error while using POST. And the website you gave does not have any steps. Kindly provide a relevant link.

Comment: I didn't expect you to click that link without altering it first

Comment: Working now. The issue was with the user authorization setup in moodle, that is not a very intuitive process. Thanks for the support.